# base64 in htaccess for url rewriting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, base64

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^infos/)^(.+?)/?$ /dl.php?f=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

this htaccess will transform mydomain.com/somefile to mydomain.com/dl.php?f=somefile
But i am wondering if it would be possible to base64-encode the "somefile" part ($1) ? 
So the value that is passed to $_GET['f'] would be encoded and i would just decode it in my php file

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: lol why not do it in the php?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to base64-encode the parameter in your URL after the request has been sent to your server. You're trying to implement the encoding functionality in the wrong place. You should implement the encoding you want while the URL is constructed, and not try to encode the URL just before you process it

Comment: I can't encode it before the URL is processed. Too long to explain. Please just answer my question...

Comment: how is this any different than  `$_GET['f']=base64_encode($_GET['f']);` ?

Comment: Because i need to encode to base64 BEFORE it is passed to the GET value. What if /dl.php?f=some&bogus=name+with&special=chars ???? It won't work because special chars needs to be escaped somehow. If the htaccess base64 encodes it, then it will work.

Comment: the htaccess is on *your* server rewritten a url that has just arrived at the very same server - get it?

Comment: I don't have the control on the URL that arrive at my server. I just want a way to base64 encode through htaccess... is this possible or not ?